# Why Authentication in my Code always return False value when i try to login?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I use `CheckUser` Function to make a login code, and i have tried to googling it and use final in variable which used by inner class, and still can't through that authentication

DBHandler.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager.db";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(User contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getUsername()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPassword()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

    // Getting single contact
    User getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        User contact = new User(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

        return contact;
    }
    public boolean checkUser(String Username, String Password) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                KEY_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = KEY_NAME + " = ?" + " AND " + KEY_PH_NO + " = ?";

        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {Username, Password};

        // query user table with conditions
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                       //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    String getUser(String Username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(Username) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        User contact = new User(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

        return contact.getUsername();
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<User> getAllContacts() {
        List<User> contactList = new ArrayList<User>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                User contact = new User();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(User contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getUsername());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPassword());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(User contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

User.java

```
/**
 * Created by asemJr on 2/12/2018.
 */

public class User {
    public String Username;
    public String Password;
    public int ID;

    public User( int ID,String username, String password) {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "Username='" + Username + '\'' +
                ", Password='" + Password + '\'' +
                ", ID=" + ID +
                '}';
    }

    public  String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        Username = username;
    }

    public  String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

in that EditText, even input is right, still return false Value. I have tried to print out the result from checkUser function in DBHandler.java, and that print is False

Autentikasi.java

```
package com.itdel.asemjr.dwgapps;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by asemJr on 2/2/2018.
 */


import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;

/**
 * Created by asemJr on 2/9/2018.
 */

public class Autentikasi extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase DWGApps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        w.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device doesnt Support Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  Message.message(getApplicationContext(),"Insertion Successful");
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device Support Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }


//        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
////        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
//        db.addUser(new User(22, "as", "ss"));
//        db.addUser(new User(221, "ass", "sas"));
//
//        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
//        List<User> users = db.getAllUser();
//
//        for (User us : users) {
//            String log = "ID: " + us.getID() + " ,Username: " + us.getUsername() + " ,Password: " + us.getPassword();
//            // Writing Contacts to log
//            Log.d("Name: ", log);

             EditText EUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
             EditText EUserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
            Button BMasuk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BMasuk);

        DBHandler login = new DBHandler(this);
        //login.addContact(new User(4,"admin", "admin"));
         String Username = EUsername.getText().toString();
         String Password = EUserPassword.getText().toString();

         final Boolean Login = login.checkUser(Username,Password);

        BMasuk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (Login) {
                        Toast.makeText(Autentikasi.this, "Username and password is correct",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent ILogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(ILogin);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(Autentikasi.this, "NOT ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // Do something in response to button click
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose I would recommend:

Changing this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                       //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order

    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
```

To this:

```
long rowsCount = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries (db, 
                                                TABLE_CONTACTS, 
                                                selection, 
                                                selectionArgs);
```

Is more performant and targeted to what you want to check.

Obviously, rememeber to change the variable name on the `if` below.

You can check [queryNumEntries Android doc here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and solution, is it right? i still did'nt find that right solution                       `long rowsCount = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries (db,
                TABLE_CONTACTS,
                selection,
                selectionArgs);
        //cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (rowsCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }`

Comment: @AndreyCls If I understood your question correctly, this should be the way to go for your issue. you could also change in a few ways the `if` that you have below, but it's off-topic. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: still can't work for me, do you have any suggestion?